# Asp.net - Remove Folder Structure From My URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigateurl

Appologise if this has already been asked but I have an `asp.net` website and all my footer pages are stored in Visual Studio under

*Views > Footer > [Page Names]*

When i click on a footer link, my URL is displaying as:

http://www.mysite.co.uk/Views/Footer/testpage

What i'm after is removing the "/Views/Footer" from the URL so it loks like:

http://www.mysite.co.uk/testpage

I have no idea how to do this.  Could someone please give me step by step guide on code to use and where to put it so that it does this.

when ever i try double clicking on my `Global.asax` file it automatically opens the `Global.asax.cs` file which i suspect is also wrong

Comment: This is easy to do in MVC, but I would google URL rewrite.

Comment: @Cyberdrew When i try to open my `Global.asax` file it automatically opens the `Global.asax.cs` file as i have just added to my post so how can i do it because all the helps i have found say i need to do this

Comment: Is your app webforms or MVC? For MVC, it is super easy to do with registeringroutes.

Comment: @TGarrett It's webforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference to system.web.routing to project

add urlroutingmodule to http module in config:

```
    <configuration> 
   ... 

   <system.web> 
      ... 
      <httpModules> 
         ... 
         <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 
      </httpModules>
   </system.web> 

   <system.webServer> 
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> 
      <modules> 
         ... 
         <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 
      </modules> 


      <handlers>
         ...
         <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </handlers>
      ... 
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Define routes in global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
} 

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{ 
   // Register a route for Categories/All 
   routes.Add( 
      "All Categories",
         new Route("Categories/All", new CategoryRouteHandler()) 
      );

   // Register a route for Categories/{CategoryName} 
   routes.Add( 
      "View Category",
      new Route("Categories/{*CategoryName}", new CategoryRouteHandler()) 
   );

   // Register a route for Products/{ProductName} 
   routes.Add( 
      "View Product",
      new Route("Products/{ProductName}", new ProductRouteHandler()) 
   );
}
```

Create route handler classes

```
public class ProductRouteHandler : IRouteHandler 
{ 
   public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) 
   { 
      string productName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["ProductName"] as string; 

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productName)) 
         return Helpers.GetNotFoundHttpHandler(); 
      else 
      { 
         // Get information about this product 
         NorthwindDataContext DataContext = new NorthwindDataContext(); 
         Product product = DataContext.Products.Where(p => p.ProductName == productName).SingleOrDefault(); 

         if (product == null) 
            return Helpers.GetNotFoundHttpHandler(); 
         else 
         { 
            // Store the Product object in the Items collection 
            HttpContext.Current.Items["Product"] = product; 

            return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/ViewProduct.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

create asp.net pages that process request:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   dvProductInfo.DataSource = new Product[] { Product }; 
   dvProductInfo.DataBind(); 
} 

protected Product Product 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      return HttpContext.Current.Items["Product"] as Product; 
   } 
}
```

This is a good reference to work off, I have used this in the past on webforms apps and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not using MVC, then you can implement an IHttpModule. There are several guides on the Internet on how to do this, such as Scott Guthrie's here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net